# Left Join on Empty Table Returns Error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So I have a few tables in my database. Let's say I have

```
CREATE TABLE ARTICLE (
  id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  time_stamp BIGINT(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  body TEXT NOT NULL,
  title VARCHAR(255),
  web_address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE BLOG (
  id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  time_stamp BIGINT(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  body TEXT NOT NULL,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE LINKTABLE (
  id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id INT,
  quote_id INT,
  article_id INT,
  blog_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES Blog(id)     
    ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  FOREIGN KEY (blog_id) REFERENCES Blog(id)       
    ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES Article(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  FOREIGN KEY (quote_id) REFERENCES Quote(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Now, if I have the following command:

```
SELECT b.id as blog_id, l.blog_id as linktable_blog_id, l.id as linktable_id
  FROM linktable l
    LEFT JOIN blog b ON 
      (l.blog_id=b.id OR l.parent_id=b.id)
```

where there exists an entry in linktable and blog that satisfies the constraints I get returned the following as I would expect:

```
{"blog_id":1,"linktable_blog_id":1,"linktable_id":1}
```

**HOWEVER** supposing I have

```
  SELECT a.id as article_id, b.id as blog_id, l.blog_id as linktable_blog_id, l.id as linktable_id
  FROM linktable l
    LEFT JOIN blog b ON 
      (l.blog_id=b.id OR l.parent_id=b.id)
    LEFT JOIN article a ON 
      l.article_id=a.id
```

Where there is neither an article nor an entry in the linktable I get returned

```
{}//empty
```

Where what I am trying to do is get

```
{"blog_id":1,"linktable_blog_id":1,"linktable_id":1, "article_id": null}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it can be reached by using UNION for 2 separate joins..

Comment: maybe...but I want to avoid UNIONs as it makes the scala code nastier.

Comment: What about writing the second join as inner select query to use in "or where in ()"?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work - where in () requires predefined categories, and I don't know a priori what fields will be in the tables im querying.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep all *blogs* then `blog` needs to be the *first* table in the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.id as article_id, b.id as blog_id,
       l.blog_id as linktable_blog_id, l.id as linktable_id
FROM blog b LEFT JOIN
     linktable l
     ON l.blog_id = b.id OR l.parent_id = b.id LEFT JOIN
     article a 
     ON l.article_id = a.id;
```

Comment: I think I want something like this (where I keep all the articles AND blogs, but not the linktable necessarily). ```      SELECT a.id as article_id, b.id as blog_id, l.blog_id as linktable_blog_id, l.id as linktable_id
      FROM blog b, article a
        LEFT JOIN linktable l ON 
          (l.blog_id=b.id OR l.parent_id=b.id)
        OR
          l.article_id=a.id```

Comment: @PeterWeyand Don't mix join styles, and, better still, only use explicit join syntax (so not implicit, comma-join syntax).

Comment: This example doesn't work btw: `anorm.AnormException: 'article.id' not found, available columns: ARTICLE.ID, ARTICLE_ID, BLOG.ID, BLOG_ID, LINKTABLE.BLOG_ID, LINKTABLE_BLOG_ID, LINKTABLE.ID, LINKTABLE_ID`